# uwsgi cannot work on a cloud server

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have install uwsgi on a cloud server, with test I write a python script to test it, which is as follow:

```
# test.py
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"] # python3
```

Then I run it as follows:

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

and I get some info like this :

```
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root
detected binary path: /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7840
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8001 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 8524)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:53307 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, May  6 2015, 18:35:37)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1108510
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72768 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1108510 pid: 8491 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 8491, cores: 1)
```

But when I type the Ip address and port on a browser, it cannot echo "Hello World".

Comment: I do the same thing on my laptop, it runs good. I doubt if it's something I got wrong on a cloud server.

Comment: Check the firewall rules. Arbitrary ports like 8001 tend to be disabled from outside access out of the box. Should work just fine from the command line on the server, e.g. `$ curl localhost:8001`.

Comment: Yes! use curl localhost:8001,I get "Hello World" on the command line. Thank you! That should be a firewall problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the firewall rules. Arbitrary ports like 8001 tend to be disabled from outside access out of the box. Should work just fine from the command line on the server, e.g. `$ curl localhost:8001`.